# nodejs PythonShell, how to export variables in run function

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, revitpythonshell

I want to export variable named completed so that I can use this out of PythonShell.run function. Is there any suggestion? here's my code.

python code

```
#test.py
import sys

def hello(a,b):
    print("hello and that's your sum:", a + b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
    b = int(sys.argv[2])
    hello(a, b)
```

javascript code

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    args: [1414, 2323]
  };

PythonShell.run('./photos/filterPhoto/test.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const completed = results; 
///results: ["hello and that's your sum: 3737"]
  });

console.log(completed)



Error : ReferenceError: completed is not defined
```

Comment: did you try to use `console.log(completed)` inside function `PythonShell.run`? `const completed` may create local variable which doesn't exist outside `PythonShell.run`

Comment: Yes, I've trid. It was like this , results: ["hello and that's your sum: 3737"]. I want to export this variable out of PythonShell.run

Comment: maybe before `run()` create global variable `let completed = "";` and inside `run()` only assign new value `completed = results;`

Comment: I've tried that, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [JSPyBridge/pythonia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pythonia) to call the Python script:

Through ES6 imports:

```js
import { python } from 'pythonia'
const test = await python("./test.py")
await test.hello(2, 3)
python.exit()
```

Or through CommonJS imports:

```js
const { python } = require('pythonia')
async function main() {
  const test = await python("./test.py")
  await test.hello(2, 3)
}
main().then(() => python.exit())
```